# only first few hundred samples are read from input stream into byte array(the rest are zeros)

Tags: java, android, audio

i'm trying to  convert audio(mp3/wav etc.) to byte array. i did it using inputStream to byte array conversion.
the problem is that after few hundred samples i recieve only zeroes. 
at first i thought the problem was with the file so i tried debugging with another file and had the same problem.
I thought the problem was with the code so i tried using IOUtils and got the exact same resualts.

can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

the code i used:

```
File file = new File(path);
final InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] byteSamples = inputStreamToByteArray(inputStream);

 public byte[] inputStreamToByteArray(InputStream inStream) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
```

the alternate version using IOUtils:

```
byte[] byteSamples = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
```

update : i tried doing it using BufferedInputStream, still the exact same results.

```
byte[] byteSamples = new byte[(int)file.length()];
    try {
        BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        buf.read(byteSamples, 0, byteSamples.length);
        buf.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: change 8192 with 1024 and let me know .

Comment: @Radhey It didn't help, still the same resualts

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the streams when done.

Comment: that's true, tnx for reminding me, but it's not answering my question.

Comment: Have you looked at the file contents with some sort of editor? Something that will show byte values instead of chars. Then you can see exactly what you are trying to read. I realize you tried two different files. Just saying, it would eliminate one point of ambiguity.

Comment: i did a similiar thing in c# for a pc app and got good results